# How can I access with PHP a key of JSON objects which is either email or phone number at the same position in an array?

Tags: php, json

I made a signup where you can signup with either email or phone number, and the system will only store either.
The way I do it:

```
if ( fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ) ) {          // call the function which checks if is a valid email
     $jNewUser->email = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign an email key to the object user
} 
else if ( fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ) {  // call the function which checks that it should only contain                                                                     digits
        $jNewUser->phonenumber = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign a phonenumber key to the object user
}
```

The functions which detects the different formats:

```
function fnCheckEmailFormat ( $sNewUserEmail ){ //checks if the email is a valid email format
    $sNewUserEmail = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber'];
    if ( !filter_var( $sNewUserEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){
        return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
    }
    return true; // else it will run the signin.
}

function fnCheckDigitFormat ( $sNewUserPhoneNumber ){ //checks if the phonenumber it conatains only digits
    $sNewUserPhoneNumber =  $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber'];
    if ( !preg_match( "/^[0-99]+$/", $sNewUserPhoneNumber ) ){
        return false; // returns false if its not valid. Then it wont run the if.
    }
    return true; // else it will run the signin.
}
```

So my text file will look the following:

```
[
    {
        "role": "admin",
        "id": "59df4ef2d8d39",
        "email": "a@a.dk",
        "name": "A",
        "lastname": "A",
        "password": "1",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfb91515810.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59df4f1b070e6",
        "phonenumber": "12345678",
        "name": "B",
        "lastname": "B",
        "password": "2",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59e37de69475b.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc0cb07985",
        "email": "c@c.dk",
        "name": "C",
        "lastname": "C",
        "password": "3",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc0cb06c5f.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc22f26f78",
        "phonenumber": "87654321",
        "name": "D",
        "lastname": "D",
        "password": "4",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc22f2638d.png"
    },

]
```

Now my question is when I am editing the account how can I grab the email or  phonenumber key as one and assign a new value to it ( again it can be an email or a phonenumber? For example `$ajUsers[$i]-> ? = $sNewUserEmailorPhoneNumber;`I hope it´s understandable what I want.

Comment: Why not save the email or phone number in the 'id' field? The emails are globally unique, and the phone numbers can be as well if you enforce the same format.

Comment: But that´s not what I want. I want to distingush beetween them. Is there any way to do this? Or it´s impossible?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I advise you to refactor your code, you should not be using the POST data in your format check functions

```
if ( fnCheckEmailFormat ( $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber'] ) ) {          // call the function which checks if is a valid email
     $jNewUser->email = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign an email key to the object user
} 
else if ( fnCheckDigitFormat ( $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber'] ) ) {  // call the function which checks that it should only contain                                                                     digits
        $jNewUser->phonenumber = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber']; // then assign a phonenumber key to the object user
}
```

even better you would have two methods on your object something like:

```
public function setIdentifyingAttribute($emailOrPhone){....}
public function getIdentifyingAttribute(){....}
```